# Are there any pitfalls of using Doctrine with PostgreSQL in Symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

We're starting a new Symfony project and we made a decision (based on performance, load tests) to use Doctrine ORM with PostgreSQL in place of MySQL / MariaDB.

MySQL is more preferred DB choise for Symfony projects ([[symfony][mysql]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony+mysql?sort=newest), [[symfony][postgresql]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony+postgresql?sort=newest)), so choosing PostgreSQL is a rare decision and maybe there are some pitfalls those we have to consider.

**The question is does Symfony Doctrine ORM integration support PostgreSQL as good as MySQL?**

Comment: Once the ORM supports the both databases - PostgreSQL and MySQL it should expose the same functionality. But _it should_ doesn't mean _it must_. Also integrating Doctrine in Symfony may add different limitations. Because of that I think the question is reasonable and it may be better for the community to be reopened. Thanks!